Probability of pulling all colored balls of a given color subset from several boxes
I have the following basic probability question, but somehow I'm having a mental hiccup lately.
The setting is relatively simple. I have $N$ i.i.d random variables attaining values in $C=\{ 
0,...,m-1 \}$. Each value is obtained with probability $\frac{1}{m}$. Given a nonempty subset $C'\subseteq C$ with $\vert C'\vert =k$, I am trying to compute the probability that all values in $C'$ is attained. I am assuming that $N>k$, and am motivated by the case where $N\gg m$.
I can define for each $k$-subset $A\subset \{1,...,N \}$, an event $S_A$ for when the $C'$ is attained on $A$. Then the union of all such $S_A$ will be exactly the event that all values in $C'$ are attained. The probability of $S_A$ is simply $\frac{k!}{m^k}$, but I'm unsure how best to deal with the intersections of these events.
I can obtain bounds on this probability using the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I think I am missing something simple.
I would appreciate any pointers to what I am missing.

Consider the complementary event, ie, $C’$ isn’t attained. For each $c\in C’$, let $B_c$ denote the event that $c$ is not attained. The probability of the union of these events as $c$ varies over $C’$ should be easy to compute, using inclusion-exclusion.

By symmetry you can assume WLOG that $C'=\{0,\ldots,k-1 \}$.
For each $j\in \{0,\ldots,k-1 \}$, let $A_j = \bigcap_{i=1}^N \{X_i\neq j\}$ so that the probability $p$ under consideration is
$$p = 1-\mathbb P \left(\bigcup_{j=0}^{k-1}A_j\right).$$
Given a subset $J\subset \{0,\ldots,k-1 \}$ with cardinality $c\in \{1,\ldots,k\}$, $$\mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{j\in J} A_j\right) = \mathbb P\left(\bigcap_{i=1}^N \{X_i\notin J\}\right) = \mathbb P(X_1\notin J)^N = \left(1-\frac cm\right)^N.$$
Finally by the inclusion-exclusion principle,
$$p = 1-\sum_{c=1}^k (-1)^{c+1}\sum_{\substack{J\subset \{0,\ldots,k-1 \},\\ |J|=c}}\left(1-\frac cm\right)^N = 1-\sum_{c=1}^k (-1)^{c+1} \binom{k}{c}\left(1-\frac cm\right)^N.$$

This can also be done using combinatorial classes from Analytic Combinatorics. We get from first principles the class specification
$$\def\textsc#1{\dosc#1\csod}
\def\dosc#1#2\csod{{\rm #1{\small #2}}}
\textsc{SEQ}_{=k}(\textsc{SET}_{\ge 1}(\mathcal{Z}))
\textsc{SEQ}_{=m-k}(\textsc{SET}(\mathcal{Z})).$$
This gives the coefficient of an EGF which is
$$N! [z^N] (\exp(z)-1)^k \exp(z)^{m-k}.$$
Expand the first powered term to get
$$N! [z^N] \sum_{c=0}^k {k\choose c} (-1)^{k-c}
\exp((m-k+c)z)
\\ = \sum_{c=0}^k {k\choose c} (-1)^{k-c}
(m-k+c)^N
\\ = \sum_{c=0}^k {k\choose c} (-1)^c
(m-c)^N.$$
Converting the count to a probability we have on dividing by $m^N$ the
closed form
$$\sum_{c=0}^k {k\choose c} (-1)^c
\left(1-\frac{c}{m}\right)^N.$$
